# Function to see the previous instance of a matching search key

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table

```
Assigned | Estimated Hours |
------------------------------
JM       |    16           |
ND       |    5            |
JM       |    0            |
DD       |    0            |
ND       |    2            |
ND       |    16           |
```

I want to achieve the following results

```
Assigned | Estimated Hours |
------------------------------
JM       |    16           | 
ND       |    5            |
JM       |    0            |
DD       |    0            |
ND       |    2            |ND's last task in row 3
ND       |    16           |ND's last task in row 6
```

If I use match function in row 7 it always returns 3, which is not what I want.
Can it be achieved without writing any custom function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://bit.ly/1JijHXt

In Column C (first helper column), return the number of times that assigned person appears in the list above (and including) that particular row.

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)
```

In Column D (second helper column), return the row number of the previous time that assignee showed up.

```
=if(C2=1,"", SMALL(ARRAYFORMULA(if($A$2:$A$7=A2,row($A$2:$A$7),row(A7)+1)),C2-1))
```

In Column E (output), concatenate to get your desired string.

```
=if(C2=1,"",A2&"'s last task in row "&D2)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. New to excel so had difficulty applying the formulas

Comment: No problem - do you mind marking this as solved (green check below the arrows on the left?